# XMLHttpRequest.open, does it work on remote websites?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused about this.

Does XMLHttpRequest work on a remote URL or does it have to be a local file? There seems to be mixed information on the net.

According to w3.org: *The XMLHttpRequest  object can be used by scripts to programmatically connect to their originating server via HTTP.*

But I've seen it used to access non-local web pages (in vista gadgets for instance for rss feeds) without using a proxy...

Enlighten me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the environment. If you run your JavaScript on a regular web page, XMLHttpRequest won't be able to connect to any other site. (That's what w3.org says, and browsers do implement this restriction.) However, in some contexts (such as Vista gadgets and Greasemonkey), it it possible to connect to any site in an AJAX request.

Comment: Nakes sense. Doesn't that bypass the security precautions though? Wouldn't gadgets be capable of xss?

Comment: Yes, they are capable of xss. If you don't trust them, don't install them.

Answer (score 0):

On a standerd web page you cant however in an app with authorised permissions you can such as a chrome extension with the permission "http://*" set. In my opinion this is a stupid restriction for normal web pages any damage/harm that can be done with it could be done using an iframe and the browsers refuse to disable them  (long over due in my opinion).