# How to get Remote File info using   AJAX?

Tags: ajax

I am new to AJAX and I have a question about `XMLHttpRequest.open(method,url,async)` method. My question is what would be the  url in the method in case of file in other Server(i.e. file in remote machine) ? . My understanding is I have to open ssh connection if the file is in unix machine and same with Windows machine .Can any one suggest code snippet ?
Correct me if I am wrong

Thanks in Advance,

Raj

Comment: a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931468/xmlhttprequest-open-does-it-work-on-remote-websites

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_httprequest.asp and you will understand how to use the `XMLHttpRequest.open(method,url,async)` method.

Comment: AYK - On SO we also try to give a code example in addition to just posting a link. The idea is that if the link ever goes dead, SO can still be a strong resource and stand on it's own. Plus, you get more rep that way as other users tend to upvote more detailed answers. ;)

Comment: Thanks @jmort253. I thought he needs a basic tutorial first. Will try to explain in details next time. :)